# shelling order of a polytope

Tags: geometry, definition, polytopes

I'm reading an article concerning the reconstruction of "relatively simple" polytopes from their skeletons and fall on this:

"Let $P$ denote a $d$-polytope and let $F_1,\dots,F_s$ be a shelling order of it's polar $P^*$."

What does this mean? On wikipedia I found the definition of shelling for a simplicial complex but not all polytopes are simplicial complexes.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Strictly speaking no polytope is simplicial complex.. It's geometric realization on the other hand may be!

Comment: Yes you are right. It may be or it may not be :-p

Comment: but what is a shelling order of a polytope?

Answer (score 1):

There is a notion of shelling for polyhedral complexes: a polyhedral complex of pure dimension $d$ is shellable if there is an ordering $F_0,\dots,F_t$ of its facets such that for every $i$ the intersection of $F_i$ with the union of $F_1,\dots,F_{i-1}$ is a $(d-1)$-ball and it is the beginning of a shelling of the boundary of $F_i$.

If your complex is a simplicial complex the part ''and it is the beginning of a shelling of the boundary of $F_i$'' is superfluous, but in general it is not.

See, eg, chapters 16, 17, and 19 in "Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry", Third Edition, 2017. (Prerpint version available here: http://www.csun.edu/~ctoth/Handbook/HDCG3.html